# PHP фильтры $_GET

Tags: php, уязвимости

```
<?php
$a = "123";
$get = $_GET['a'];
echo "test ".$get;
?>
```

Почему если в браузере ввести **test2.php?a=".$a;** , то выводит **test ".$a;** , а не **test 123** ?

Comment: потому что выводите `$get`, а в ней лежит текст `'$a'`. если нужно вывести значение переменной указанной в гет-параметре, то так и пишите `$$get`. и почитай про переменные переменных. это ж самые основы http://php.net/manual/ru/language.variables.variable.php

Comment: В строку попадает значение $a, в двойных кавычках хватит $a для выполнения. Через GET не работает не $a, не $$a!